# What adventures lie in Laketown from The Hobbit in The One Ring

Tags: adventure-writing, the-one-ring

**Spoiler**

> <snark>Smaug dies in *The Hobbit*.</snark>

As I re-read the classic book, I'm struck by the details that offer adventure opportunities. We learn what happens to Laketown, the Master, Bard and many others east of Mirkwood and in the shadow of the Lonely Mountain.

But it is this passage that I'm curious if *The One Ring* visits, set in the 60+ years between the end of *The Hobbit* and *The Fellowship of the Ring*

> [The people of Laketown] removed northward higher up the shore; for ever after they had a dread of the water where the dragon lay. He would never again return to his golden bed, but was stretched cold as stone, twisted upon the floor of the shallows. There for ages his huge bones could be seen in calm weather amid the ruined piles of the old town. **But few dared to cross the cursed spot, and none dared to dive into the shivering water or recover the precious stones that fell from his rotting carcass.**

There is so much to enjoy in the above passage.

Is Laketown, Smaug and the region given much detail in *The One Ring* and if so, do we see opportunities to explore unanswered or open questions from the book and/or create new adventures in the region?

Comment: A definite +1 from me. I was struck by the very same paragraph and have been planning an adventure round it for quite a while, with orcs and other dark creatures making sinister use of the bones. (That's why I've asked the following Q on SF&F: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28850/what-happened-to-the-carcass-of-smaug-after-the-events-of-the-hobbit ) Looking forward to the answers. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an entire mini-supplement on Laketown (aka Esgaroth), comprising 35 pages. It is, however, almost totally focused upon the town, tho' it does include some marsh dwelling monsters for use en route.

There is no curse *mechanically*, but a brief mention of the *belief* in one. Likewise, mention is made of the darkening of the marshes, and their acquiring blighted status... but that fate, to a greater or lesser degree, afflicts all of the Mirkwood, and in fact, all of Middle Earth, as Sauron grows in power.

Note: Smaug is mentioned by name 12 times - thrice in a letter from Glóin, son of Gróin, to Bilbo Baggins, and thrice in the section on Dragontide.

There is no surrounds map - only the city map itself.

Pages 5-10 are descriptions and key to the City itself. 
Page 17-18 is the map proper, presented as a 3/4 view painting of the city.
Pages 11-12 & 14 are new fellowship actions relating to Esgaroth.
Page 13 is coinage information
Pages 15-16 & 19 are about the annual events for Dragontide, the feast celebrating the anniversary of the death of Smaug
Pages 20-23 discuss the Marshes and the Blight
Pages 25-30 are Lake-man character generation.

Comment: The remains of Smaug is looking more and more like an oversight on _TOR_. A regional map with the location of old Laketown, etc. Surprising really, given the depth of everything else in the game. Narratively, I find it hard imagine that an event such as the death of a dragon would go forgotten in 60 (and some odd) years between _Hobbit_ and _LoTR_. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: The remains **are** mentioned. No effect of them is mechanically provided. There's even an annual festival commemorating the Death of Smaug. And, on a 10-mile hex map (in the core), the lake is too small to show both locations.

Comment: thanks. the mention did not stand out in your answer (which I'm inclined to accept).

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of possibility for creating adventures and plot hooks in that brief description of cursed dragon bones.

1. What form does the curse take?

   - Is it on anyone who lingers too long?
   - Is it on any of the jewels?
   - Is it on the bones and the jewels?
   - Is one of the jewels legendary?

---

2. Does someone steal the bones, knowing they're cursed?

   - If so, why?
   - What plans does the thief have?
   - If they're selling to the highest bidder, what is the bidder doing?

---

3. Could someone find a way to resurrect the dragon?

---

4. Maybe some of the poorer folk of Laketown decide to live on the site.

   - What happens to them?
   - Does a tribe of Orcs discover them?

---

5. Do the dragon bones cause a mutation in the fish?

   - Is the arrow that slew him still there?
   - Is it a force for good, or evil?
   - Would another dragon be interested in it?

---

Oh yeah, all kinds of possibilities.

Comment: This is a brainstorm of ideas but it's on the edge of not really answering the question posed.